# RA-AJAX download anywhere?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I realise the RA-AJAX team have some legal stuff going on right now.. although I was eager to try their 1.0 version of the RA-AJAX library...

I'm not sure if I am allowed/can access the library from somewhere else (i.e. another download site etc) or if it is totally banned at this time??  I know it was meant to be open source... it actually looks really excellent..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Howdy, the project is up running now again, and you can find the download at http://ra-ajax.org

Read the details here; http://ra-ajax.org/lawsuit-settled-the-war-is-over.blog

And here; http://ra-ajax.org/new-release-of-ra-ajax-version-2-0-out.blog

Comment: Thanks Thomas!  good to see you guys back again!!  from the early testing/playing with ra-ajax, it looks very excellent.. we are a small startup in Australia.. not sure how easy it would be to employ your services at some time.. I will be sure to contact.

Thanks again!

Comment: Great David. Let us know if you get stucked at stacked (he, he) ... ;)

Comment: @Dav.id HI, do you startup business? I also startup in india, can we meet online. I need to discuss something about business proposal with you..  can you give me your email Id?